# Generated Dependencies issue

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I generated dependencies for my project using the following target.

Only the first line of the generated dependencies are compiled.

Then, my main file depend on all the sources file in my project;
any ideas?

My dependency file generated like this:

```
rules.d : $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard *.h)
        gcc -MM $(wildcard *.c) > rules.d
```

Then I did

```
-include rules.d
```

then only the first generated dependency is compiled.
`rules.d` contains for example

```
main.o:main.c *.h
a.o=a.c
b.o=b.c
c.o=c.c
```

We have the following files in the project

```
a.h a.c 
b.h b.c 
c.h. c.c
```

`main.c` (contains the main function), and all the header files are included.
I am splitting my project this way as it is mandatory from the team.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem: "Only the first line of the generated dependencies are compiled." ?

Comment: I don't understand why people go around marking these questions as "close" because they're "not about programming".  In what universe does writing makefiles not count as programming?

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation.  I also can't understand how you got the results you did in your `rules.d` file.  I've never, ever heard of `gcc` generating variable assignments like `a.o=a.c` into a dependency list.  I've also never seen it generate a wildcard prerequisite like `*.h`.  Are you sure you actually correctly cut and pasted the contents of the file into your question?  if so there must be something more to your makefile than you provided here.

Comment: When asking questions it's always a good idea to show the command line you entered to invoke `make`, and the (relevant) output you got, and a specific description of the way in which it's not what you wanted.

Comment: @dash-o rules.d have main.o: *.h main.c / a.o:a.c / b.o:b.c / c.o:c.c . onle the first part is evaluated through gcc which will result in main.o only

Comment: Please edit your question to make it accurate, rather than adding corrections in the comments.

Comment: @MadScientist: `I don't understand why people go around marking these questions as "close" because they're "not about programming".` - That close votes are about "no clear problem statement", and this is what the question **actually** lacks.

Comment: Maybe my browser is broken but when I click on the "close" link all three votes are assigned to _off-topic because the question does not appear to be about programming_ and none of them are assigned to _unclear what you're asking_.  Even so IMO "unclear" close votes should be reserved for confusing questions in a single short paragraph with no supporting details.  Here the OP _tried_ to provide details, they just weren't clear enough.  IMO this should elicit a comment asking for clarification not a close vote.

Comment: The issue was solved, it depends on where I should put my include as @MadScientist said, the other thing was to specify my object files as dependencies for my executable

Answer (score 0):

When you say *only the first dependency is compiled*, I assume what you mean is that when you run `make`, only `main.o` is compiled or `rules.d` is generated.

That's likely because you added the `include rules.d` and/or the target for building `rules.d` at the *top* of your makefile.  It should be added at the *end* of your makefile.

If you invoke `make` with no explicit target, then it will build the first target it finds in the makefile and stop there.  If you put the rule for building `rules.d` as the first thing in the makefile then that's all that will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

after obtaining a list of all the desired dependency files via:

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
```

then:

```
rules.d : $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard *.h)
<tab>gcc -MM $(wildcard *.c) > rules.d
```

should be:

```
%.d: %.c 
<tab>gcc -MM $< > $@
```

And then the compile statement should be:

```
%.o: %.c %.d 
<tab>gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c $< -o $@ -I.
```

and somewhere toward the end of the make file should be:

```
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

Comment: Note: if working with C++ source files, then instead of `gcc`, use `g++` or `gpp`

Comment: Might make sense to modify the '%.d' rule to regenerate if any '.h' file was updated. Will cover the case of nested .h files.